# Failed to Make ipa file

Tags: ios, iphone, ipa, account, apple-id

When I try to achrvie the Xcode  showing the message " Fetching list of teams from the Developer portal " . It always timed out. Can't fetch the team.

[image]
[image]

I Accounts it Showing Apple Id not having any Development Teams. I have added the Apple Id

[image]

Comment: Change your network or wait for some time

Comment: low internet connectivity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have just tried to make same and it's working properly for me. So, problem is not from Apple Side.

Please check your internet connection properly and try again.

Comment: In theory, Apple Support status should give us a hint if anything is red: https://www.apple.com/es/support/systemstatus/

Comment: Can you please try again and check ? I hope you checked your internet connection,

Comment: Internet connection is fine because, I can use in other mac machienes. I am sharing my mac machine wifi only for those mac.

Answer (score 1):

Apple is facing some big problems for last two weeks and due to iTunesConnect Outage they are facing some problem in uploading the new application on AppStore. But here you can also check if your internet connection is good and make sure it is not low internet connectivity.

Here there is also some issue with Xcode 6.2 so better you delete the team and add them again and try to upload the application via Xcode.

In case you are still facing the same issue then better export the .ipa file and upload with "Application Loader" software from Apple.

Comment: My internet connection is good. I have deleted and added the same . It is validating fine but still it showing the " Not on Any Development Teams"

Comment: Can you try to export to .ipa instead of Submitting directly to AppStore via Xcode Organiser.

Comment: I couldn't make ipa file

Comment: Internet connection is fine because, I can use in other mac machienes. I am sharing my mac machine wifi only for those mac.

Comment: I am not uploading to Appstore. Trying to make ipa file only.

Answer (score 0):

It's because of **low internet connectivity**. If your internet connection is not proper then you cannot get an apple account through which you can make an IPA.

Comment: Internet connection is fine because, I can use in other mac machienes. I am sharing my mac machine wifi only for those mac.

Answer (score 0):

July 2015

I'm using XCode 6.4, and today, its been happily building Ad-Hoc .ipas for me all day, but now, on the same MacBook Pro, it's timing out every time on this same "Fetching list of teams from the developer portal" message.

Sometimes, it (eventually) returns a "The request timed out" message, sometimes I just get this...

[image]

And no, this *isn't* an internet problem...

This issue has been reported on several StackOverflow threads over the past few months.  Usually it works, but sometimes it doesn't, and, in usual Xcode fashion, it gives no hint as to the cause/solution.

(How can the same company produce such a fantastic OS and hardware, yet their development environment is so consistantly bad, year after year...?)

**Update**

Sigh.

Out of desperation, I rebooted my MacBook, and now, it happily manages to load the list of teams.

(Just closing all Xcode instances wasn't enough to fix the issue.)

Welcome to the 1990s, folks.

Answer (score 0):

I've tried everything that been said. Nothing works, what I do is try and cancel every moment that you know it will fail. Like a traffic that cant continue because of load of request.